# Apply color until certain height to a Container | Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've a container which has height: 600. Now I want to apply it a background color but only until height 200. Is this possible in Flutter ? My limitation is that I cannot use multiple containers or any other widget to achieve this. **I can only make changes in this existing widget.**

```
Container (
  height: 600,
  color: Colors.blue //Only apply until height 200
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`LinearGradient`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html) for this. You can play with this snippet, especially `stops`.

```dart
Container(
  height: 600,
  width: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
    gradient: const LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Colors.transparent,
        Colors.red,
      ],
      stops: [4 / 6, 4 / 6],
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think LinearGradient is the only option but you should apply small trick to get rid of smooth transition, below code snippet would work for you

```
  Container(
    height: 600,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        stops: [200 / 600, 200 / 600, 1],
        colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.transparent, Colors.transparent],
      ),
    ),
  )
```